# Would you be willing to review my 100a Sub Panel Plan?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, garage, subpanel

Seeking an experienced person to review the attached schematic for my 100a sub panel - which will be in an adjacent detached garage.  I am comfortable working with my hands and doing the wiring.  But I want to make sure my approach is sound - as I have not done a sub panel before.  I've gotten to this point by researching the other posts.  Thank you for those too!

Would you put this in your house?  If not - is there something I can change to make it better?

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're asking a new question instead of updating your existing one?

Comment: I would seriously consider using aluminum instead of copper, and use some of the savings on an even bigger panel.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I stacked the two pix in Photoshop, and made one 50% translucent and inverted it. That makes differences pop up and turns everything else gray. It's all gray. This is the same picture.  I think OP is trying to say "BUMP" like on a forum.  OP, editing your question causes a bump.   But yes, we do owe you some attention.

Comment: I meant no disrespect or rule breaking. I had done an update to my post several days ago and it seemed to make no difference. The post stayed at the bottom of the page getting no additional views.